# google cloud platform authorization code

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have a google cloud platform server and currently we need to have a new authorization code. We currently don't have support from the development team which built this before. How do we obtain this? A simple step-by-step guide would be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello everyone. To clarify my inquiry I'll provide our current setup and issue being encountered. We have this setup where PO files are created via salesforce, then these PO files are pushed to an FTP site via php script hosted in google cloud server. Last Jan. 17 the PO are no longer pushed to the FTP and upon investigation, we found out that when salesforce attempts to connect to google cloud server, the reply was invalid authorization code. Salesforce dev support advised that we need to obtain a new authorization code from google.

Comment: We current;y don't have developer support for the google cloud server and community support is only available. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems your issue is on some kind of integration between Google Cloud Platform and Salesforce, also the information it's no very clear, for you what is a PO file?, which service you are consuming? an API, a VM machine, APP Engine?. One

I think you need to identify exactly which service you are consuming and from there you can investigate further.

Comment: Hi DavidC, yes google cloud platform integrates with Salesforce via API. Now, what happens is that whenever Salesforce connects to google cloud platform, the server replies that the authorization code or access token is invalid. We need assistance on how to obtain a new access token or authorization code. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.